# Configure Angular with ASP.NET Core on Azure App Service

Tags: angular, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, deployment

I have a web app with **Angular** and **.NET 5** and I want to host it on 2 different **Azure App Service** (one for the Test environment and one for Prod).

I have followed the page https://angular.io/guide/build and created the following environments:

- environment.ts
- environment.test.ts
- environment.prod.ts

The web app I'm publishing from Visual Studio from a .pubxml file (I have 2 different ones for each app service).

**How can I configure the App Services to use separate Angular environment variables?**
For example:

*App service A -> environment.test.ts*

*App service B -> environment.prod.ts*

I assume there should be some additional changes done to **package.json** and some to the .NET web project.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below steps if it helps to fix the issue:

1. In `project.json` file > **`publishOptions`** section > include a new application setting called `appsetting.{env}.json`.
2. In the Azure Web Application > Select **application settings** > Add setting `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`  and set it.

For more steps, follow this  [Configuration with Azure App Services and ASP .NET Core](https://blog.elmah.io/configuration-with-azure-app-services-and-aspnetcore/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've already done this configuration for the ASP.NET Core app. The question is how can I do something similar for the Angular app? I've edited the initial question to avoid confusion.

Comment: Okay, I understood. Looks like configuring stack (frontend+backend) application with Azure App Service. Hope this documentation site helps you:  https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/01/08/angular-net-core-sql-on-azure-how-to-deploy-a-full-stack-app-to-microsoft-azure